# Number of placements

Tags: combinatorics

This is a fairly simple example, but for some reason I can't understand solution, so I decided to recreate it myself and got stuck.
I have 9 boxes and 9 balls - 7 white and 2 black. How many ways there is to deploy balls into boxes?
My way of thought is: the order is important to us. So let's line the boxes:
$$|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|$$
Clearly we have 10 walls. 2 of them aren't going to change their position, so we work only with 8. So, I count number of permutations of 11 elements with 3 groups: $${17! \over 8!7!2!} = 875160$$

The correct answer is $289575$. Either the order isn't important (and then I don't know that to do), or my thought is missing some important detail. As I vaguely recall, my thought is somewhat close to solution. What have I missed?

Comment: I think order _within_ a box is ignored. So `||BW|W|WBW|W|W` and `||WB|W|BWW|W|W` count as the same solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If balls of the same colour are indistinguishable,  use Stars and Bars to count the number of ways of placing the whites. Use Stars and Bars to find the number of ways of placing the blacks. Multiply.